# How to post data to tables with relationships in angular 8

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

In my angular project, by using API, I need to post data to tables with relationships, what is the best way to do that because when I try to use post method I face this error: (Internal Server Error) while the get method working well, or is there a way better more than that? 
this is **Model.ts**

```
export class Clients {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    phone:string;
    address:string;
    type:string;
    account:number;
    nots:string;
    branchId:number;
}
```

in my **Service .ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Clients } from './clients.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientsService {

  clientsUrl="http://localhost:4200/api/clints"

  client: Clients;


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
getAllClients():Observable<Clients[]>{
    return this.http.get<Clients[]>(this.clientsUrl);

}
addClient(){
return this.http.post(this.clientsUrl,this.client)

  }
```

**compennt.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    ...

    //post data
    this.Service.client = {
      id: 0,
      name: null,
      phone: null,
      address: null,
      account: 0,
      nots: null,
      branchId: 0,
      type: null,
    }
  PostClient() {
    if (this.Service.client.id == 0) {

      this.Service.addClient().subscribe(res => {
        this.Service.getAllClients()
      },
      )}
    else {
      this.Service.editClient().subscribe(res => {
        this.Service.getAllClients()
      },
        err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
  }
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: If you share the internal server error message that is probably going to help alot. You'll also want to post the data being sent as well as the api code. As far as angular is concerned, your post looks correct, its more an issue of making sure your sending with the server wants to receive.

Comment: What is `this.client` in service.ts, it seems that you do not initialize it.Besides, the `addClient` needs an `Observable<any>` return type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happened because of the DB still empty, so there is no record in ***branchTbl*** yet and the problem solved by change default value for `branchId` form **0** to **null**

```
ngOnInit() {
    ...

    //post data
    this.Service.client = {
      id: 0,
      name: null,
      phone: null,
      address: null,
      account: 0,
      nots: null,
      branchId: null, 
      type: null,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that jumps out at me:

clientsUrl="http://localhost:4200/api/**clints**"

Did you mean **clientsUrl="http://localhost:4200/api/clients**"?

Be sure that route matches what you have set in your API.  Secondly, make sure the model you're sending from client side matches what your DTO properties are set to.

Check your network traffic as well during testing and see what the Request Body is (shows what you're sending)

Comment: Yes the URL is right as I mention and everything is right also and working normally, except the  post method, after check  network I found the error happened in server-side, I solved it and will write the answer to be a benefit for the others